# multiple selection using regex

Tags: python, regex, text, pattern-matching

HI i have a multiple patterns need to be extracted. My start and end markers are different combination.
It can contain

```
ITEM 3              Quantitative and Qualitative Disclosures about Market Risk
As part of its Bank Credit  Agreement,  the Company was  required to purchase an
interest rate cap of $100 million for 
item 4
```

or it can be

```
item 3.            Quantitative and Qualitative Disclosures about Market Risk
As part of its Bank Credit  Agreement,  the Company was  required to purchase an
interest rate cap of $100 million for 
item 4
```

or it can be

```
item 3a              Quantitative and Qualitative Disclosures about Market Risk
As part of its Bank Credit  Agreement,  the Company was  required to purchase an
interest rate cap of $100 million for 
item 4
```

I am using regex as

```
qaq =r"item[^a-zA-Z\n]*\d\s*\.\s*Quantitative and Qualitative Disclosures about Market Risk.*?item[^a-zA-Z\n]*\d\s*\.*"
```

I an using python. My question is do i have write multiple regex for each pattern or can i do it in one regex. If it can be done in one then how can i implement this.

Answer (score 0):

Regex:

```
^(?:ITEM|Item|item)\s\d[a-z]?\.?\s*Quantitative and Qualitative Disclosures about Market Risk(?:.*\n)*?item\s\d.*$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xzbBz1/3)

Explanation:

`(?:ITEM|Item|item)` - non capturing alternate group to handle `item` in various cases.

`(?:.*\n)*?item\s\d.*$` - non capturing group of any number of characters followed by `\n` repeated zero to unlimited times in a lazy manner `*?` followed by lowercase `item` followed by space followed by a digit followed by any character (0 to unlimited) followed by end of line `$`

Answer (score 0):

In your regex you use `[^a-zA-Z\n]*` to match what is between `item` and a digit. In this case I think you could use `\s` instead.

At the start you have `item 3`, `item 3.` and `item 3a`. You use `\d\s*\.` to match those 3 variations but that would only match `3.`

You could match the `item` variations at the beginning using the case insensitive flag or specify the case insensitive [modifier](https://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html) `(?i)` and add the multi-line mode `(?m)`.

[`(?im)^item\s\d+[a-z.]?\s+Quantitative and Qualitative Disclosures about Market Risk\n(?:.*\n)*?item\s\d+$`](https://regex101.com/r/nIlAm9/1)

**Details**

- `^` Assert the start of the string
- `item\s\d+` Match item followed by a whitespace character and one or more digits
- `[a-z.]?\s+` Match an optional lowercase character or a dot followed by one or more digits
- `Quantitative and Qualitative Disclosures about Market Risk\n` Match literally followed by a newline character
- `(?:.*\n)*?` Repeat any character zero or more times followed by a newline because [the dot does not match line breaks by default](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html)
- `item\s\d+` Match items, a whitespace character and one or more digits
- `$` Assert end of the line

[Demo Python](http://rextester.com/NPRU57392)